# Show basic circuit diagrams in code

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics, diagram

Suppose I have the following circuit image of an example XORD gate using AND, OR, and NOT gates:

[image]

Are there any open source tools that are capable of converting this into text characters, so that I can show the diagram inside text documentation without having to link to the image? An example of a square being drawn using ASCIFLOW would be:

```
+-----------------+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 +------------------>
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

But I'm trying to see how to create basic circles, triangles and other gate-shapes.

Comment: use european logic symbols .... example here ... http://wakerly.org/DDPP/DDPP3_pdf/IEEEsyms.pdf

Comment: If it's really just two inputs and one output, a truth table might be easier to write in plain text and convey the requirements just as well.

Comment: David, I've written software that can translate schematics drawn with ltspice into ascii schematics using fixed spaced fonts. It works well and can handle schematics like the one you show. But it has been a few years since using it for newsgroups, which require ascii and I've not released the code.

Comment: @jonk awesome! Would you be interested in sharing? If so, could I shoot you an email?

Comment: @David542 If I can find the time -- in short supply. I have the code, but it targets 16-bit x86 right now using the last 16-bit C compiler that Microsoft released. (It's a DOS-based system, command-line, and uses the DOS interrupt calls to paste the results into the Windows clipboard -- a call that is no longer supported with CMD.EXE under the newer windows versions.) I'd need to verify that I can rebuild it on a 32-bit or 64-bit and adjust some of the code for that purpose before attempting to share it. Otherwise, I'd be in unlimited support discussions as someone else re-targets the code.